# Sorting with sql server and collation and unicode

Tags: sql-server, localization

I've got a table in sql server, and one of the columns is used to store multilingual data, it's current nvarchar(250).

When sorting the column on the web front end I would like to take the user's locale into account so e.g spanish is sorted correctly taking "ch" into account.

I'm a bit lost in how to do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 onwards, you can specify a COLLATION name in an [ORDER BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) clause, so you could construct your query dynamically and choose the collation name:

```
[ ORDER BY 
    {
    order_by_expression 
  [ COLLATE collation_name ] 
  [ ASC | DESC ] 
    } [ ,...n ] 
]
```

But be sure to read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table
WHERE ...
ORDER BY <column> COLLATE Spanish_CI_AI;
```

You can specify a specific collation to a column during operations using [`COLLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx). This act as a cast of the type data to the specified collation.